# DBI/SQL performance on SELECT via different methods?

Tags: sql, perl, dbi

I've been looking around and haven't been able to find a good answer to this question.  Is there a real performance difference between the following DBI methods?

- fetchrow_arrayref vs
- selectall_arrayref vs
- fetchall_arrayref

It probably doesn't matter when making a single `SELECT` call that will give a smallish (>50 records) resultset, but what about making multiple `SELECT` statements all in a row?  What about if the resultsets are huge (i.e. thousands of records)?

Thanks.

Comment: When in doubt, [`Benchmark`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Benchmark)

Comment: As @TLP says, benchmark!  You might also check out DBI::Profile to help you with that.  http://search.cpan.org/~timb/DBI-1.50/lib/DBI/Profile.pm  That'll tell you where you're spending time in database calls.  NYTProf will tell you where you're spending time in the rest of your code:  http://search.cpan.org/~timb/Devel-NYTProf-5.06/lib/Devel/NYTProf.pm

Comment: After more research I found these: http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=273952 ... http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TIMB/DBI_AdvancedTalk_200307/index.htm

Answer (score 3):

The key question to ask yourself is whether you *need to keep all the returned rows* around in memory.

If you do then you can let the DBI fetch them all for you - it will be faster than writing the equivalent code yourself.

If you don't need to keep all the rows in memory, in other words, if you can process each row in turn, then using fetchrow_arrayref in a loop will typically be much faster.

The reason is that the DBI goes to great lengths to *reuse* the memory buffers for each row. That can be a significant saving in effort. You can see the effect on [this slide](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TIMB/DBI_AdvancedTalk_200307/sld018.htm), although the examples don't directly match your question. You can also see from that slide the importance of benchmarking. It can be hard to tell where the balance lies.

If you can work on a per-row basis, then [binding columns](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/TIMB/DBI_AdvancedTalk_200307/sld019.htm) can yield a useful performance gain by reducing the work of accessing the values in the fetched rows.

You also asked about "huge" results. (I doubt "thousands of records" would be a problem on modern machines unless the rows themselves were very 'large'.) Clearly processing a row at a time is preferable for very large result sets. Note that some databases default to streaming all the results to the driver which then buffers them in a compact form and returns the rows one by one as your perl code (or a DBI method) fetches them. Again, benchmark and test for yourself.

If you need more help, the [dbi-users mailing list](http://lists.perl.org/list/dbi-users.html) is a good place to ask. You don't need to subscribe.

Comment: Comment not of course intended for Tim but for OP. If you do have a lot of rows or if each row is large and it would consume a lot of memory you can process N rows at a time with fetchall_arrayref and max_rows. That way you get the benefit of faster fetching but can process the result in chunks of rows. See example in fetchall_arrayref at https://metacpan.org/pod/DBI#fetchall_arrayref

Answer (score 0):

The difference between fetchrow* and fetch all will be the location of the loop code in the call stack. That is, the fetchall* implies the fetch loop, while the fetchrow* implies that you will write your own loop.

The difference between the fetch* and select* methods is that one requires you to manually prepare() and execute() the query, while the other does that for you.  The time differences will come from how efficient your code is compared to DBI's.

My reading has shown that the main differences between methods are between *_arrayref and *_hashref, where the *_hashref methods are slower due to the need to look up the hash key names in the database's metadata.

Comment: It's a little-known fact that you can pass a prepared statement handle to select*_* methods like selectall_arrayref.

Comment: @tjd I'm relative certain that neither Tim nor all the millions of DBI users would allow selectall_arrayref to prepare the query more than once.  So if you're speak of selectrow vs fetchrow, you're right, but I also cannot write an answer to take into account every possible (and possibly braindead) use case.

Comment: @TimBunce - when you said little-known, I though maybe you also meant "undocumented" but there is is clearly in docs for each select* method.  Today TimB personally taught me something about DBI. :-)  Thank you Tim.